# Getting scalac: Error: Error compiling the sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.11.8-62.0' during running scala spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, bigdata

**build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
ThisBuild / libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Spark_Practice"
  )
```

**Error:**

> scalac: Error: Error compiling the sbt component
> 'compiler-interface-2.11.8-62.0' sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: Error
> compiling the sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.11.8-62.0'  at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.handleCompilationError$1(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:436)
> at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:453)
> at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$5$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
> at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:490)  at
> sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:500)   at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:448)
> at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
> at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:490)  at
> sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:500)   at
> sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:440)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:163)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$1(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:61)
> at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242)   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:54)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:23)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.$anonfun$createCompiler$3(CachingFactory.scala:24)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2(Cache.scala:20)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)     at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:24)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.doCompile(LocalServer.scala:43)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:30)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.compileLogic(Main.scala:209)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.$anonfun$handleCommand$1(Main.scala:192)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.decorated$1(Main.scala:182)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.handleCommand(Main.scala:189)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.serverLogic(Main.scala:165)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:105)
> at
> org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)   at
> com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.runImpl(NGSession.java:312)    at
> com.facebook.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:198)

Comment: change scala version to 2.11.12 in build.sbt

Comment: Seems like a version mismatch between spark and scala

Comment: Can't reproduce. Scala 2.11.8 seems to work with Spark 2.4.8 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0Qk3wTpnQh2vytlLiFDlFg  (tab "Build Settings") https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8jfGPzmySzWh54fB7kmX6g

Comment: How do you build your project when you get the error? Do you open it in IDE or run `sbt clean compile`? Try the latter.

Comment: Now im getting scalac: Cannot connect to compile server at localhost/127.0.0.1:3200 (Connection refused: no further information) [SBT_New_SCALA]
Trying to compile without it

Comment: @BhaveshSonawane You didn't answer how you build your project. *"Now im getting scalac: Cannot connect to compile server..."* Where do you get this message? In IDE? Restart Scala compile server

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same error. If you use Intellij Idea, you can try to solve this issue by changing the JDK to 1.8.

- Open the Settings
- Find 'Scala Compiler Server' under the Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler > Scala Compiler
- Change the JDK to 1.8

[image]